# Assign dataframe head results to another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Here is the scenario.

1. Millions of data from source.
2. I'd like to get a sample 10k records only.
   `df = record.head(10000)`
3. Search the 10k records. Get the first record who's specific column is not null.

   `df[~df['af_ad_id'].isnull()].head(1)`

This is returning an error -- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isnull'.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting that error because `df['af_ad_id']` is of type `None`

Comment: hi. can you elaborate?

Comment: print(df['af_ad_id']) and you should get `None`

Answer (score 0):

Let try `df[~df['af_ad_id'].isnull()][0]`

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: Let catch the error as `len(df[~df['af_ad_id'] ) == 0` or empty dataframe let say you either expand the 10k records to 100k or check the error case.